# How to set session Id in Apex (Salesforce to Salesforce Integration via SOAP)?

Tags: apex, webservices, soap

I have created a webservice class in Salesforce Org B (destination).

The purpose of this webservice is to accept values and create a custom object record  in Org B.

1. I generated partner WSDL from Org B and imported into in my Org A (my Source Salesforce Org).
2. I generated WSDL for my webservice class from Org B and again imported into my Org A (it created two classes)
3. After adding the remote site settings I wanted to testdrive sending data from Org A to Org B.

This is the code snippet that I tried it in anon apex.

```
partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap p = new partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap();
String uname = 'UNAME';
String pwd = 'PWD+TOKEN';
partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult e = p.login(uname,pwd);
System.debug('The result of the login call is => '+e);
System.debug('ServerURL = '+e.serverURL);//Line 1
System.debug('Session Id = '+e.SessionId);//Line 2



soapSforceComSchemasClassCreateRec.rec rm = new soapSforceComSchemasClassCreateRec.rec();

rm.documentdate = '2016-02-25 00:00:00';
rm.documentid = '1';
rm.Name = 'Test';
soapSforceComSchemasClassCreateRec.rec rd1 = new soapSforceComSchemasClassCreateRec.rec();
rd1.createDocument(rm);
```

I am able to make a successful handshake and get serverurl and sessionId (Line 1 & Line 2).

After authentication, I am trying to invoke the actual webservice method for creating record and I am getting the following error as below.

[image]

I believe it is because I have not set the session Id which I received from Line 2 during the actual invocation.

Can someone tell me how do I actually set the session Id in my request ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `loginResult.sessionid` for `sessionid`

```
partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap obj = new partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap();
partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult loginResult = obj.login('org@username.com', 'Password');
obj.SessionHeader = new partnerSoapSforceCom.SessionHeader_element();
obj.endpoint_x =loginResult.ServerUrl;
obj.Sessionheader.sessionid = loginResult.sessionid;
```